# twitter api 1.1 statuses/user_timeline

Tags: php, rest, twitter

I had written my original code for 1.1 using Abrhams twitteroauth and OAuth.php back in late 2012 and the code was using the /1/ endpoint.  It worked fine as in I could connect, get authorized, get a long term token, get updates and tweet... no problems.

When 1.0 was sunsetted the functionality broke (duh!) and it took a long time for it to end up back on my desk.  The first thing I did was change the api from /1/ to /1.1/ and we're mostly working... I say mostly... there are some problems:

Problem 1:
I'm authorizing, getting a token etc. I can login to a test account (@test1) and manually tweet, that tweet is picked up via statuses/update and processed according to our needs.  If that tweet is directed to a specific user (@test2) then statuses/update on test2 never detects the incoming tweet although its seen on the twitter @ tab as an "Interaction".

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                            $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$params = array('screen_name' => $tw_name,
                  'include_entities' => "TRUE",
                  'since_id ' => $tw_last);

$results = $twitter->get('statuses/user_timeline', $params);
```

Problem 2:
When I try to tweet/reply (almost all of my tweets will be in_reply_to) on behalf of a user the post never returns but apparently the tweet gets sent (this may be a problem with twitteroauth.php)

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                            $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$user = $twitter->get('account/verify_credentials');

// build a tweetback @address
// might be our own address but lets see... 
$message = "@" .$tweetback['tw_src'] ." $message";

// tweet the reply      
$tweet = array('status' => $message, 'in_reply_to_status_id' =>$tweetback['tw_topicid']);

// post the tweet
$response = $twitter->post('statuses/update', $tweet);
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this stuff?

Comment: #1: what is `include_entities`, i don't know if thats in the API ... you need to use `statuses/mentions_timeline` to see mentions

Comment: #2: I don't understand your question or problem.

Comment: include_entities is in the api, it expands the data sent to include more non-cryptic info... I think the default is true.  The mentions_timeline... just found that one... wonder why it was picking those up without a specific and seperate call on the /1/ api and not /1.1/ - Now each user needs two calls... crap!  Still having the posting problem.

Comment: okay i see it now, but its always set to true in 1.1

Comment: you're right... ok, taking that one out!

Comment: Still leaves me with the issue of the statuses/update not returning...

Comment: so nothing comes back to `$response` ?

Comment: no. it simply never returns...